# Get file owner on Windows with Ant

Tags: windows, ant

I'm writing an ant function that builds a very simple delivery note. one of the things I'm trying to track is the owner of an file. As this is a Win solution the only thing I can think of doing is to use an exec task to do a dir /q to a file and then hook out the file owner from the listing. I need to skip the first 5 lines then pull out the user name following the \

```
Volume in drive D is Data
Volume Serial Number is xxxx-yyyy

Directory of d:\test\zips

29/11/2016  13:19            32,706 SERVER\Administrators file.zip
        1 File(s)         32,706 bytes
        0 Dir(s)  151,247,241,216 bytes free
```

Unfortunately no matter what I'm doing in the reqexp I'm not getting any match, but regexp is new to me and as yet I've not got it sussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how that works in Ant, but to get the user and filename you can use `.*\/.*?(\w+\\\w+) *(.*)` as the regex.
Then after running it on the windows output, the user will be in $1 and the filename in $2.

You can try it here : https://regex101.com/r/9RGqLz/6

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the output of `dir /q` with regular expressions is error-prone. New versions of Windows could change what `dir /q` outputs and Ant scripts could break.

Instead, consider using PowerShell to get the owner of the file:

```
> powershell "Get-Acl d:\test\zips\file.zip | foreach { $_.Owner.split('\')[1] }"
```

The above command outputs:

```
Administrators
```

In an Ant script, this becomes:

```
<exec executable="powershell" osfamily="windows" outputproperty="owner">
    <arg value="Get-Acl d:\test\zips\file.zip | foreach { $_.Owner.split('\')[1] }"/>
</exec>
<echo>Owner: ${owner}</echo>
```

The above script outputs:

```
 [echo] Owner: Administrators
```

Comment: thanks. I do see your point. In this instance I'll stick to the dir /q purely because it doesn't introduce a 'new' item with power shell. Eventually I'm going to have to change it and add Linux commands too, so may be implement it then.
Thanks :)